# Is it possible to health check a Kubernetes API server over HTTP or TCP?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, digital-ocean, kubernetes-health-check

I need to load balance a cluster of Kubernetes API servers (version 1.7) on DigitalOcean, but the problem is that the Kubernetes API server seemingly only supports HTTPS and the DigitalOcean load balancer can only do [HTTP or TCP health checks](https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/v2/#load-balancers).

Is there any way to perform health checks of the Kubernetes API server either via HTTP or TCP?

Answer (score 6):

do a kubectl proxy and then use postman or any tool to send a get request to 
http://127.0.0.1:8001/healthz/poststarthook/apiservice-status-available-controller

you can use other too

- `/healthz`,
- `/healthz/autoregister-completion`,
- `/healthz/ping`,
- `/healthz/poststarthook/apiservice-registration-controller`,
- `/healthz/poststarthook/apiservice-status-available-controller`,
- `/healthz/poststarthook/bootstrap-controller`,
- `/healthz/poststarthook/ca-registration`,
- `/healthz/poststarthook/extensions/third-party-resources`,
- `/healthz/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers`,
- `/healthz/poststarthook/kube-apiserver-autoregistration`,
- `/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers`,
- `/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers`,
- `/healthz/poststarthook/start-kube-aggregator-informers`,
- `/healthz/poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-informers`,

Answer (score 2):

You can hit API server nodes on port 8080 at `/healthz` and expect to get back a 200 with a body of `ok` if the API server is up and in good health.

See some test code that hits this endpoint for more details: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/fe3e7482764ace362b465405c45780d03a8c6706/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/server/healthz/healthz_test.go#L28